# Unable to obtain results from multiprocessing with pooling

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing, dill, pathos

Firstly apologies for any mistakes I make. I am new to StackOverflow and I'm still getting used to it.

The Background:
I try to train multiple keras models via multiprocessing. Those Keras models are stored in three lists (currently 50 models per list). The function I use has three models as inputs (one of each list) as well as some training data and an ID. The output should be an evaluation score and the given ID.

My first try was importing multiprocessing from the standard python library.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

It turned out that this multiprocessing application does not work, because of the pickle as a serialization tool. So I downloaded Pathos and Dill in order deal with this Problem. My Code goes like this:

```
    from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
    p = Pool()
    from pathos.helpers import freeze_support
    import dill

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        freeze_support()

        result = p.amap(training.train_critic, models_actor_t, models_critic, models_critic_t, batch_states_list, batch_actions_list, batch_rewards_list, batch_new_states_list , batch_terminals_list, sub_epochs_list, id_list)

        print(result)
```

If I run this code, everything works fine and I get this output.

```
<multiprocess.pool.MapResult object at 0x000001D42CEC09E8>
```

If I add the method result.get() the trouble starts.

```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
        freeze_support()

        result = p.amap(training.train_critic, models_actor_t, models_critic, models_critic_t, batch_states_list, batch_actions_list, batch_rewards_list, batch_new_states_list , batch_terminals_list, sub_epochs_list, id_list)

        print(result)
        print(result.get())
```

The out goes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:/Users/Lennart/PycharmProjects/demonstrator_RLAlgorithm/GeneticAlgorithm/GAoperations.py", line 192, in <module>
    print(result.get())
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\connection.py", line 209, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\reduction.py", line 53, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 408, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 744, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 729, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 729, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 729, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 744, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 520, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 627, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 871, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 814, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 840, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 774, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 801, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 520, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 627, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
```

The last part from this on repeats itself:

```
 File "C:\Users\Lennart\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Cense5\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 871, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there something fundamentally wrong?
2. The Keras Models are stored in a list. So by inserting them into the function, the weights of the models are still persistent, right?

Again, I´m sorry if I did any stupid newbie stuff.

Thank you,

Lennart